Angular 18 SSR with Firebase Functions
I am trying to deploy an angular application with SSR enabled to firebase.
Locally everything is running (using the port 4000) etc, I have a browser and a server -bundle in my dist-directory.
However when firebase deploys, using the firebase deploy hosting, it seems that the backend is not deployed.
Now since I do have a server-bundle, it seems, that I just need to upload it to firebase, using the 'functions' property in firebase.
It seems though, that this firebase functions expect a full node project setup, with its own package.json etc.
It feels like there should be a more intuitive way to upload the backend code, which is already bundled.
Ans suggestuions?
firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/shone-halachot/browser",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssr"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "dist/shone-halachot/server",
    "runtime": "nodejs18",
    "main": "server.mjs"
  }
}

without the function section, I run into the error ssr function could not be detected.
It makes sense that the server need to run after the deployment something like
npm run serve:ssr:shone-halachot after deployment, which basically is:
node dist/shone-halachot/server/server.mjs

which I tried to express with the firebase.json script



